# How to reset proxy settings

Tags: 18.04, proxy

In order to install some packages, I somehow copy-pasted several lines of code that changed my proxy settings in Ubuntu 18.04 terminal and now it is causing errors endlessly. I just want to reset my proxy settings to the initial state without changing any others like network settings, how do I do this?

Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Update:

For anyone having the same problem, I resolved the issue by typing the followings in my terminal. Basically I removed all the configurations I have changed for proxy.

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
npm config rm registry
```

Then, it allowed me to do things normally like installing packages. Hope this helps!